# Can't receive coming from Contacts on IOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, share

I am using  share_handler package. I'm handling a vcf file when I tap on share contact on android side. However, on the IOS side, the media is empty. I shared a screenshot. There is no file or string in media value.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you getting this file? Did you create it?

Comment: I am tapping on share link in contacts

Comment: And your app appears in the share sheet? Can you show the screenshot of that?

Comment: Yes it appears as you can see the new screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with editing share_handler package. First of all I forked package to this repo

https://github.com/osmantuzcu2/share_handler

and I have edited this native code on this commit.

https://github.com/ShoutSocial/share_handler/compare/main...osmantuzcu2:share_handler:main

While debugging, I realized that the incoming data is of text type, but because the append method gave an error, the else part was working. I wrote a searialization in this part and returned the phone number.

```
if let item = data as? String {
        sharedText.append(item)
    } else {
        let contact = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data as! Data)
        let go = contact.first?.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? "number"
        sharedText.append(go)
    }
```

Comment: Also you can see an example on this repo https://github.com/osmantuzcu2/shareNumber